# Combine Specific Results from a Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

I want to group a table by a specific category.

The categories look like: `"AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", etc...` Using the code below, I can easily get results for each group. However, there is a special case where two categories should be combined and a new Key generated (e.g. Category BBB and DDD should end up as one category).

My end result should be something like:
Key: "AAA", Items: (items under AAA)
Key: "BBB/DDD", Items: (items under BBB and DDD)
Key: "CCC", Items: (items under CCC)

I have been at this for a while and can't get anything that works.

```
var query= ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(g => g.Field<string>("category"))
            .Select(a => new workType
            {
                Key = a.Key,
                Item = a.ToList()
            });

public class workType
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public List<DataRow> Item { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Don't see how this is possible without some parameters. You're selecting on a `key` which you say is 'AAA', 'BBB'..etc. You would have to provide some other functionality, like `Key = a.Key || b.key`. I don't see a generic way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, all you need to do is to transform the key before grouping by it:

```
var sequence = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();

var result = sequence
        .Select(e => new { Key = GetCompoundKey(e.Field<string>("category")), Value = e })
        .GroupBy(e => e.Key)
        .Select(g => new { Key = g.Key, Items = g.SelectMany(e => e.Value).ToList() });


private static string GetCompoundKey(string originalKey)
{
    if (originalKey.Equals("BBB") || originalKey.Equals("DDD"))
    {
        return "BBB/DDD";
    }

    return originalKey;
}
```

Besides that, `GroupBy` has an overload that takes `IEqualityComparer<T>` so you could write an `IEqualityComparer<string>` implementation and use it:

```
private class KeysEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        if (x.Equals(y))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return (x.Equals("BBB") && y.Equals("DDD"))
            || (x.Equals("DDD") && y.Equals("BBB"));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string str)
    {
        return str.GetHashCode();
    }
}

// your original code using the comparer:
var query= ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(g => g.Field<string>("category"), new KeysEqualityComparer())
            .Select(a => new workType
            {
                Key = a.Key,
                Item = a.ToList()
            });
```

I'm not sure if this is a good idea though as you will most probably get weird group keys that you'll need to modify anyway. And then the modification code lives in different place than the comparison code, even though the logic should be the same. So that's asking for some trouble in the future.

Comment: The problem with your approach is that it would create a composite key `BBB/DDD` even in situations when only `BBB` or only `DDD` categories are present. This may or may not be what OP wants.

Comment: Your first solution accomplished exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Just out of curiosity, is there actually some proper use-case where you'd first group something by superset and then be interested what subset do the elements come from? Why would you then group by the superset at all?

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek Your question implies a solution, which is not unique. You can solve by grouping on superset only after analyzing the subsets. It turns out that OP simply mis-categorized BBB and DDD, because he treats them as a single category anyway.